# How to add data to table row using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

```
 exam_paper{
    exam_paper_id,
    exam_paper_name
}

question{
    question_id,
    question,
    option1,
    option2,
    option3,
    option4,
    answer
}
exam_question_list{

    id,
    exam_paper,id,
    question_id

}
```

**exampaper.php**

```
 <a href="addquestions_to_exampaper.php?id=<?php echo $row3["exam_paper_id"];?>">
        <button id="addques"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;Add Questions</button>
        </a>
```

**addquestions_to_exampaper.php**

```
                <?php
                $sql= "SELECT * FROM question WHERE catergory_id=$catergory_id AND level_id=1";
                $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

                ?>
<form method="post" action="addquestions_to_exampaper_action.php?exid=<?php echo $exam_paper_id;?>">

<table>

  <caption>Easy Level Questions</caption>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Question ID</th>  
      <th scope="col">Question</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

<tbody>


<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tr>

      <td data-label="Question Id"><input name="question_id" value="<?php  echo $row['question_id'];?>" readonly type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td data-label="Question" style="text-align:left"><?php echo $row['question']; ?></td>

    </tr> 

<?php
    }
    ?>

  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Add Question" name="submit" id="submit" />

</form>
```

**addquestions_to_exampaper_action.php**

```
<?php
include '../../db/db_connection.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $exam_paper_id=$_GET['exid'];

        $question_id=$_POST['question_id'];

$sql="INSERT INTO exam_question_list (exam_paper_id,question_id) VALUES ('$exam_paper_id','$question_id')";


         if (mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){

            header("Location: exampaper.php");

            exit();
         }else{ 
            $error=mysqli_error($dbcon);
         }



    }   
?>
```

I have q question pool. (question table)
I need to add questions by selecting checkboxes and need to add questions to the question paper.(exam_question_list table)

When I selecting number of checkboxes and click to add button, only one checkbox data goes to the 'exam_question_list table', other selected checkbox data not gone.

How do I fix this error?

I want to add data to the table like below
**exam_question_list**

```
**id   exam_paper_id   question_id**

1         1             12
2         1             3
3         1             45
4         1             5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define name as array

```
<td data-label="Question Id"><input name="question_id[]" value="<?php  echo $row['question_id'];?>" readonly type="checkbox" /></td>
```

Get the checkboxes  as array to in your PHP code

```
//now loop them
if(!empty($_POST['question_id'])) {
    foreach($_POST['question_id'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in G:\xampp\htdocs\WBES\src\system\modules\exam\addquestions_to_exampaper_action.php

Comment: When I use the sql code then its not work, only one selected data was gone to the table

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO exam_question_list (exam_paper_id,question_id) VALUES ('$exam_paper_id','$check')";

Comment: What is the value of $check?

Comment: echo $check; is working, then I put question_id value as $check

Comment: It means the problem is with your sql query

Comment: how to write the sql query to add this

Comment: Please check your error: 
`$sql="INSERT INTO exam_question_list (exam_paper_id,question_id) VALUES ($exam_paper_id,$check)";`  `die(mysql_error());`

Comment: how to insert all selected checkbox values into rows,

Comment: Please put your sql query in foreach loop but its not a good idea to run sql query in a loop